# What verb means "create a problem"?

Tags: translation, verbs

When creating japanese languages packages for computer languages, we have to translate the words "`raise`" or "`throw`" from computer programming jargon into everyday japanese.

What Japanese verb might be consistent with the following ideas:

> - "tell somone about problem"
> - "notify your parent or teacher of a child who misbehaved.
> - tattle-tale.
> - file paperwork for a request.
> - file a ticket.
> - generate error message.
> - send error message to person.
> - send report on consumer price indicies to our boss.
> - `throw` a baseball.
> - write the error message down on a piece of paper; crunch-up the paper into to a wad or ball. Now, throw the crumpled ball of paper at the human being who did somthing wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for one verb that covers all those meanings? And what does it have to do with giving and receiving?

Comment: @aguijonazo It is not the case that a Japanese verb would have to perfectly match all of English phrases or sentences I provided. The problem is that there is no English verb for "generate an error message" or "report a problem". Because there is no one English verb for such a thing, I provided a list of English phrases and sentences which all beat around the same bush. There is no name for that bush, per se, but there are names for things close to the bush. I was thinking that it would be helpful to have a programming language with all language keywords, such as `throw` written in Japanese.

Comment: @aguijonazo You asked what my question has to do with giving and receiving. Many programming languages give error messages and receive error message. Instead of "**give**", we write "**throw**" and instead of "**receive**" we write "**catch**". It is like throwing baseballs. One athlete throws a baseball to another athlete. There is one thrower and one catcher. One part of a computer program throws the error message to another part of the computer which catches the error message. One part of computer program gives the error message (an Exception Object) to another part of the computer program.

Comment: I know those concepts. If you imagine people working in programming, they will discuss those concepts in their own language although they type all the keywords in English. You could simply ask what verb they use for “raise” or “throw”. No need to beat any bush. In Japanese, 例外を上げる and 例外を投げる are both used commonly (例外 being “exception”). The same people would expect the keywords to be in English, though. The giving-and-receiving tag has a specific purpose. I’m removing it.

Answer (score 2):

When say "generate an exception" or "throw an error" in English, the verb IS "to generate" and "to throw". In Japanese programming, the following terms are used when taking about handling exceptions thrown by a function or whatnot

- Exception 例外
- Error エラー
- An error occurs エラーが起こる
- Process an exception 例外を処理する
- throw an error エラーをスローする / エラーを投げる
- throw an exception 例外をスローする / 例外を投げる
- catch an error エラーをキャッチする / エラーを捕まえる

When talking about throwing/catching an error/an exception the words are スローする and キャッチする (literally the English throw and catch), or the native Japanese words 投げる and 捕まえる. Both of these usages can be found on Google.